# Physically cluster a MYSQL table for better performance

Tags: mysql, database-design, cluster-computing

I have a 30M row table, which is indexed by ID now. However, a lot of the requests are around a much smaller subset, which is identified by app_user=1

Does it make sense to physically cluster the table according to this? If so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

> Does it make sense to physically cluster the table according to this?

I think it does make sense, depending on how you select your data. For example, if one of most important use cases for selecting the data is `SELECT fields FROM tablename WHERE app_user = something` then that will be more efficient if the selected records are all together, i.e. if app_user is the clustered index.

> If so, how can I do so?

I think you [Google "clustered index" for MySql](http://www.google.com/#q=clustered+index+mysql).

Comment: thanks! I think this is what you mean right?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: @ming yeow -- that's what I found when I Googled, but I can't confirm it from my own knowledge: I don't know MySQL myself.